# What does $quote->getIsSuperMode() mean in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, quote

I see a function `isSuperMode()` which is called on quote and quote item objects.
Can anyone tell me what `isSuperMode()` means in that case?

I found the code in:

1. `checkQuoteItemQty` function at class `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer`
2. Also in `_initItem` function at class `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The quote is set into super mode in 
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Session/Quote.php`:

```
$this->_quote->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Essentially it is a flag on the quote that this quote has been created by an admin. The effect of this is in the locations you stated that an admin can for example create an order for an item that normally would be out of stock or is not visible in the catalog.