# Magento 2 : keep disable product in cart

Tags: magento2, product, cart

I want to keep disabled product in cart.

Let's say I have added one product to the cart. After that I have `disabled` that product from **Magento** admin. Now when I visit `cart page`, there is message that your cart is empty. But I want to keep `disabled product in cart`.

`Persistent shopping cart` is already enabled in my case.

How to prevent **Magento** from removing the disabled items from cart?

Comment: What is your expectation with disabled products in cart? Since a disabled product can't be bought by a customer proceeding the checkout will be not possible with disabled products in the cart.

Comment: Yes but i want to allow customer to buy even disable products as well. As we are not  maintaining stock.

Comment: Then you should configure Magento not to manage stock and no product will be disabled or set out of stock.

Comment: We are not managing stock. But can not prevent magento to disable products or set out of stock.

Comment: If you do not manage stock, a very simple solution could be to set stock to 10,000 or even more and then, in Advanced Inventory, set Notify for Quantity Below to 1,000. This way you will hardly have some product go out of stock, and you get notifications when you have sold 9,000 pieces.

Comment: Out of stock is not an issue. Issue is when we manually disable product in admin, magento automatically remove products from cart.

Comment: May I ask, why would you want to disable your products but keep it available for purchase?

Comment: Why you want to disable product? what you want to achieve by disabling ?

Comment: I just simply want to allow users to order with disable products as well.

Comment: You need some kind of serious magento training

Comment: your question is totally different as you explain requirement in comments.

Comment: Hassan Ali, if we prevent magento 2 to remove disable products from cart, it means we allow users to continue order with disable products. Then whats wrong i have added in comment?

Comment: `Issue is when we manually disable product in admin`, then don't.

Comment: 'https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/29542/49186'